# Show only a subfolder of a document library in a web part

Tags: 2010, web-part, document-library, sharepoint-foundation, list-view

I want to show only a particular folder in the right pane of a page using a WebPart in SharePoint Foundation 2010.  Is this possible?  When adding the WebPart, I could only add the document library.  I didn't see a way to show only a subfolder there. I also looked at creating a view on the library, but don't see a way to filter for a folder in the view's filtering options. Is this possible?

EDIT:
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295448/sharepoint-how-do-i-filter-a-document-library-view-to-show-the-contents-of-a-su/6751423#6751423) which mentions manually editing the markup of the WebPart to add a query for the folder to query for the folder name, but no matter what I try, it always says no documents found. I added the field `FolderDirRef` to my viewable columns to make sure I had the proper folder specified, but I still get nothing.  I've tried `<Eq>` and `<BeginsWith>` and tried changing the `Value` tag's type definition from `Lookup` to `Text` and without specifying the type. If I add a new document, it gets uploaded to the document library root.  Here's the way I'm specifying the query.

```
<BeginsWith>
    <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' />
    <Value Type='Lookup'>/DocumentLibraryName/SubFolderIWant/</Value>
</BeginsWith>
```

EDIT 2:
I've changed the `<View>`'s `Scope` property to `RecursiveAll` as shown below.  With no query defined, it shows ALL documents in ALL folders (as expected), but as soon as I specify a query of any kind, it breaks, and resorts so showing no documents at all. To be clear, the WebPart isn't generating an error. It's just saying no documents found.

EDIT 3:
Here's the full view definition

```
<View Name="GUID" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="" Url="..." Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png" Scope="RecursiveAll">
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Contains>
                <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' />
                <Value type='Text'>2007</Value>
            </Contains>
        </Where>
        <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef"/>
        </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/>
        <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Modified"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Editor"/>
        <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <Toolbar Type="Freeform"/>
</View>
```

Comment: What SharePoint version 2007 or 2010?

Comment: 2010.  Will edit ? to specify.

Comment: Can you put in as much of the relavent code as possible?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to change: <Value type='Text'>2007</Value> To <Value Type='Text'>2007</Value> (A capital T for Type=)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a view on the document library and applying the query/scope changes mentioned above to the `<View>` definition in the new document library's view.  The case sensitivity spevilgenius mentioned matters, but even with that correction, I couldn't get the view to work in the aspx page's web part.

The weird thing is that it appears that when you apply a view to a web part list/document library viewer, it looks like Sharepoint copies that view's definition to the web part's definition.  And, indeed, if I look at the code of my page now, I see the exact view definition code there as well as my view.  It might work if you put the code below directly in the aspx page and skip the step where I created the view on the Document Library.  I've been beating my head against this wall since last night, though.  Don't feel like trying anymore permutations...

```
<View Name="{GUID}" Type="HTML" Scope="RecursiveAll" DisplayName="DisplayName" Url="Url-To-View" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png">
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Contains>
                <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef"/>
                <Value Type="Text">FolderIWantToShow</Value>
            </Contains>
        </Where>
    </Query>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/>
        <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered simply using a Page Viewer Web Part that points to your folder?

Also, I assume you have good reasons to use folders, but your question is typically the reason why people recommend using metadata rather than folders.

Comment: +1 for METADATA

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Sharepoint 2010 Foundation does not allow for permission based metadata which makes restricting which of your users can upload and where they can upload a tad difficult; unless, of course, folders and folder based permissions are implemented.

Answer (score -2):

It works much easier with a content query see this [link](http://salnikan.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/using-content-query-webpart-to-display-files-from-a-specific-folder/)

Comment: Please summarize the solution in your answer. Post a link to support your answer, but don't just post a link. Links can go bad and disappear any time. If you want to provide an answer that adds value, post the core message here.

Comment: Yes, while  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines. If you would like to expand this answer (without plagiarising obviously) I'll be happy to undo my downvote ;-)