# SharePoint 2013 - Doc Library WebPart to display subfolders

Tags: 2013, web-part

Usually you put a WebPart for a Document Library on a page, and this WebPart shows the content of a specific library, starting in root. Now I have some subfolders like "Marketing", "Finance" etc and I want the WebPart to show all Files and Folders under "Marketing" (without first browsing there).

I know there are solutions how I can display all files in a flat list, but I want to preserve the structure (subfolders).

Trying [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22992/show-only-a-subfolder-of-a-document-library-in-a-web-part) solution failed (not SP 2013 compatible?), any other suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this, as I am also looking for it (SharePoint 2013, not 2010 or any lesser versions). Thanks. joe

Comment: Nah, not yet. It seems that there is no solution out-of-the-box. I haven't found a third-party custom webpart which has this functionality.

Comment: Is there not a way to get a WebPart to open the doc library up directly into a subfolder?

Comment: There is, have you tried my solution? (see "Answer")

Comment: Is a javascript that forces the two web parts to open the relevant folders an option?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Search Query WebPart, where you define:

- you want to show all documents:  0x1001* (something like this its a default document content type)
- from URL: URL of your folder: https://intra/site/library/folder

*There is only one thing and that you will see files which are in index, so there can be "show latency" when you add new file if you havent enabled Continuous Crawling.*

Or you can use IFrame WebPart, where you will have a look into Library folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this (maybe more a workaround).

1. Add the WebPart to your page, save it.
2. In your WebPart, navigate to the desired subfolder and open it.
3. Take now a look at the URL of your page. It changed. If you use THIS URL (eg. put it in your Navigation) your page will open and the WebPart opens exactly the subfolder!

The URL combines several Informations:

```
http://webapp/sitecollection/site&RootFolder=selectedFolder&FolderCTID=FolderContentTypeID&View=UsedLibraryView
```

Using this Link will navigate you directly to the page and opens the WebPart in selected subfolder.

Comment: This could be one possible work around. But in scenario like having two document library web part on same page will break.