# Have a web-part display only sub-folders?

Tags: 2013, web-part, library

I am new to SharePoint 2013. I was curious how to put a WebPart for a Document Library on a page with SharePoint 2013, not 2010.

This WebPart would then show the content of a specific library folder and not start at the root of the folder. So say I have a library with multiple folders like "Marketing", "Finance" etc,

I want to be able to create a web part that would only show the contents within the “Marketing subfolder and all of it contents. Is this possible?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to display the subfolders only of a specific root folder? None of the above methods are that useful and I can't get any of them to work.

Comment: Hi, have you tried using metadata tags? you can tag the contents of the folder and then configure search and views.

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of ways to achieve this like creating a view on the document library and applying the query/scope changes mentioned above to the  definition in the new document library's view.

You can check the following links to achieve this. These links are got 2010, but same would applicable for 2013 also.

[Show only a subfolder of a document library in a web part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22992/show-only-a-subfolder-of-a-document-library-in-a-web-part)

[How do I filter a document library view to show the contents of a subfolder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295448/sharepoint-how-do-i-filter-a-document-library-view-to-show-the-contents-of-a-su)

[Create a webpart to show subfolder of existing document library](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/a17309b0-9666-4a11-bf8f-26662988b017/create-a-webpart-to-show-subfolder-of-existing-document-library)