# SharePoint Online Document library how to create and group more than one folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, folder, subfolders

I created on folder with subfolders and grouped by the folder name. but how to create 3 folders with subfolder for example:

Folder X with subfolders Grouped by folder X

Folder Y with subfolders Grouped by folder y

Folder Z with subfolder  Grouped by folder z

any help please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to display subfolders on the same list view with parent folders, it is not possible with built-in solutions.

It is only supported to group by folders/items on the same level. And I don’t think you can group the subfolders using parent folder name either.

---

Consider using custom solutions to **display all subfolders only** in a list view (the parent folders Folder X, Y, Z do not show up) and then apply group by feature.

See possible solutions via this post: [Have a web-part display only sub-folders?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101634/have-a-web-part-display-only-sub-folders)