# Web part showing given folder within a document library

Tags: web-part

I am trying to implement a web part that shows a given folder within a document library. Is there anyway that I can set a certain folder to be the starting point in a webpart? I am trying to also do this without displaying anything except the document library/folder.

Comment: This might help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22992/show-only-a-subfolder-of-a-document-library-in-a-web-part

Comment: I just started programming in Sharepoint and are not sure how to use the code

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by changing the link that users use to navigate to the page with the webpart in it.

Below is an example of a link I send out via email to users of a form for an item which contains a document webpart. As you can see I send a custom form, select the folder to display and use a non-default view on it.

```
http://<site>/<list>/Forms/<form>.aspx?<id>&RootFolder=<foldername>CTID=0x0120D5200046F6D724D05F4346862FFA6B7215E4A3&View={F404F7DE-F122-4D10-9E1E-5BACD9134120}&InitialTabId=Ribbon.ListForm.Edit&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence
```

The easiest way I have found to get the right url is to simply navigate and display the information manually then copy paste the url to where it is needed.

Comment: But what Web Part do I use to show the given folder?

Comment: ..The web app for the library that the folder is in